# PyQt5 Event Filter Object Detection

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I want to report the mouse position whenever I click on a point within a `QGraphicsView` widget.

```
class App(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.graphicsView.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        self.graphicsView_2.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, a0: 'QObject', a1: 'QEvent') -> bool:
        if a0 == self.graphicsView:
            if a1.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                mousePosition = a1.pos()
                print(mousePosition.x(), 261 - mousePosition.y())
                return True
            return False
        elif a0 == self.graphicsView_2:
            if a1.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                mousePosition = a1.pos()
                print(mousePosition.x(), 261 - mousePosition.y())
                return True
            return False
        return False
```

I only want it to report the mouse button when I press on one of the two `QGraphicsView` widgets I have listed. However, with this current code nothing is being triggered at any point. I assume `a0` is never equal to the `QGraphicsView` widgets I want to compare it to, so I'm unsure how to make this trigger when I want it to.

Comment: does a1.type() return a string or a number ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`QGraphicsView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) inherits from [`QAbstractScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html) so the widget you click on is not the [`QGraphicsView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) but in its [`viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport). And that seems to be understood because you install the event filter in the [`viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport) so "a0" will never be the [`QGraphicsView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) but its [`viewport()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewport). Also as you compare objects it is better to use "is".

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
if a0 is self.graphicsView.viewport():
```

```
if a0 is self.graphicsView_2.viewport():
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! This fixed my issue. `a0` was a `QWidget` every time instead of the expected `QGraphicsView`.

Comment: @mtrns "a0" can only be the same object or the QObjects where the filter was installed, in your case the viewport(), the event filter does not know if it is a QGraphicsView or a QPushButton or a QLineEdit.